# Converting a php regex to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

how to convert the following php regex to javascript regex?

```
php regex:- (?s)(?<=<a).*?(?=<\/a>)
```

Comment: Is this supposed to extract the `href="something"` part of a link?

Comment: It is used to extract all between <a> and </a> in php. It is perfectly answered below for JavaScript :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use the exact same pattern in javascript, because lookbehinds aren't supported.

The best I could do is

```
<a([^]*?)(?=<\/a>)
```

It should match the same text as the php regex, but captures the text in the first capture group instead.

Comment: `[^]*?` <-- I think this is a typo? Should probably say something like `[^<]*?` but then it would fail on `<a href="#yo"><b>click me</b></a>`. Stick with `.*?` or, you know, don't use regexes to parse HTML to begin with ;)

Comment: Hi Rawing... Exactly what I wanted and works perfectly for my scenario :) Unfortunately I do not have 15 reputation to vote up your answer :(

Comment: @funkwurm: `[^]` is intended. It's perfectly valid regex meaning "match absolutely any character, even newline".